# DRM exception: processLicense - Roku Ultra

Tags: drm, roku, brightscript, widevine, playready

I have a Roku Channel and it has live as well as non-live content, content is playing well for most of the Roku Devices but on Roku Ultra it's failing.

I am experiencing the following error:

```
<Component: roAssociativeArray> = 
{
  code: -6 
  message: "buffer:loop:unset:DRM exception: processLicense: [sess.lic.rep] KeyAdd failed : 99999(Cdm::kUnexpectedError):extra:etype:buffer"
}
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

I looked over the internet for many threads but non was helpful for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will be helpful to resolve the issue, but I experienced similar kind of issue once. As far as I know DRM libraries are downloaded separately after firmware update on Roku. So, in case you did a factory reset recently and running the side-loaded app now, there may be chances that libraries are not downloaded completely. You can try for manual system software update and see if this resolves the issue. This worked for me. Also, partner success suggested to install one channel having widevine integration and running that channel as one step to resolve the issue, although I didn't need it. You can try this step also along with system software update.